# Converting float value to NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i'm a noob in Objective C. I'm having the following confusion.

How do i convert a float value obtained from progressView.progress in a string?

I tried this

```
  NSString *progressStatus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", progressView.progress];
  label.text = progressStatus;
```

But this say EX_BAD_ACCESS

some help please.

Thank You.

Comment: Does progressView point to a deallocated object? to nil? Please post the crash log.

Comment: That should be fine.  Is progressView non-nil?

Comment: What, precisely, is the error? This is the correct way to convert a float to a string, and `progressView.progress` does return a float.

Comment: the entire code is this:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet you posted reads correctly. The most likely source of your error is that the `UIProgressView` has yet to be initialized when this code is called. It is also possible that the `UILabel` is not correctly set up.

If you created these UI elements in the IB, check the connections. If you created them programmatically, then check that they are allocated and initialized correctly.

Also ensure that you are setting the text of the label **after** the progressView is created.